# Fetch all PHP errors in array

Tags: php, error-handling

Is there any way I can get all notices, warnings, errors etc that PHP encounters stored in an array?

I need this for a custom error logger and I want it to catch also errors in addition to exceptions, which I already did.

I managed to find something for the last error, but that's not enough: `error_get_last`

Comment: Have you tried [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to build a custom error handler:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

```
$_ERRORS = array();

function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    global $_ERRORS;
    $_ERRORS[] = array("errno" => $errno, "errstr" => $errstr, "errfile" => $errfile, "errline" => $errline);
}

set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to get also the error type? (ie. notice, warning). And also, if my error handling function is part of a class, is there any way I can use it without making the method `static`?

Comment: @EduardLuca Yes, your custom error handler can be any "callback" so you could use an object and a method on it: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback

Comment: @EduardLuca the `$errno` variable contains the type of the error (for example E_USER_ERROR or E_USER_WARNING). You can find the list of possible values here: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Answer (score 3):

You could set a [custom error handler](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and then either use a static variable to collect all the errors or write them as they occur to some kind of persistent storage.

Answer (score 1):

What about
    mixed set_error_handler ( callback $error_handler [, int $error_types = E_ALL | E_STRICT ] )